# autocomplete=new-password and making them confirm it via entering the password again

Tags: html, autocomplete, passwords, autofill, change-password

html5 now has some new attribute values for the `autocomplete` attribute to assist user-agents when autofilling forms. One of the new values, `new-password`, is used to tell the user agent to enter a **new** password, opposed to the user's **current** password.

What's not clear to me though, is **how to properly tell it to generate the same password for both fields when your form makes the user enter the new password twice as a confirmation?** Maybe by using the same custom `section-*` prefix on both inputs, such as `autocomplete="new-password section-my-new-pw"`? The spec mentions the `section-*` prefix will affect the [autofill scope](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofill-scope), but it's not overly specific about what that means for my case.

Here's a sample form that I imagine will represent what many websites will soon use - it distinguishes the `current-password` from the `new-password`, and makes the user confirm the new password.

```
<form>
    <p>Username             <input type="text"     autocomplete="username"         name="username"></p>
    <p>Current Password     <input type="password" autocomplete="current-password" name="current-password"></p>
    <p>New Password         <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password"     name="new-password"></p>
    <p>Confirm New Password <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password"     name="confirm-new-password"></p>
</form>
```

I much prefer if answers reference a documentation opposed to observations about how current browsers or extensions behave.

Comment: You should not be using inputs inside paragraphs.

Comment: @undefined Why not? I've seen this practice in many examples from reputable sources for many years. i.e. [whatwg.org](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element) and [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/How_to_structure_a_web_form)

Comment: I believe it's outdated. Paragraphs are usually meant for text and using them as containers could cause issues with typography styling, especially spacing. `<div>` is usually much better for containers.

Comment: Inputs in <p> are fine in comparison to unlabeled inputs. The example should be using <label> elements

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just use autocomplete="new-password" at the confirmation input. And if you choose to generate a new password in the password input, the confirmation input gets filled with the same value instantly. Tested in chrome.

Reference:

1. [chrome advice](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/form-styles-that-chromium-understands)
2. [html standard discussion](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3531)

Comment: IMO the referenced links are more clear than this answer.  Basically you should use the `new-password` attribute on **BOTH** new and confirm password fields.

Comment: Works in Firefox too.

Comment: As opposed to Chrome, Firefox will make the first `<input type="password" autocomplete="new-password">`'s text visible, so you can copy the password until the `input` is blurred (no longer in focus).

Comment: @s3c lol, after almost 10 years in web dev your comment make me realize why it is called "blur". As in blurred image vs focused image ...

Comment: @Arthur_J Yeah, it's a clever metaphor, albeit, not a very **clear** one :)